# Underscore.js. Why does this code not produce duplicates?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

In JS, I have a dictionary. The dictionary is keyed by `id` Each item in the dictionary is of the form:

```
{ name: aName, type: aType }
```

A subset of the items have duplicate `name` fields. I want to extract the items with duplicate `name` fields.

Here is my approach using underscore.js that is **not** working:

Turn the dictionary into an array by adding the id key as an additional field to the item inserted in the array:

```
var acc = [],
    sorted,
    uniques,
    dupes;

    _.each(name_type_dictionary, function(name_type, id){
        acc.push({ name: name_type.name, type: name_type.type, id: id });
    });
```

Sort `acc`:

```
sorted = _.sortBy(acc, 'name');
```

Inspection of `sorted` reveals there are duplicates. Lets go get 'em. First grab all the uniques. I use an iteratee to specify the uniqueness criterion.

```
    uniques = _.uniq(sorted, true, function(name_type_id) {
        return name_type_id.name;
    });
```

Grab the duplicates:

```
dupes = _.difference(sorted, uniques);
```

Sort `dupe` to present in alphabetic order.

```
dupes_sorted = _.sortBy(dupes, 'name');
```

This does not appear to work. I have stared at `dupes_sorted` and can find none of the duplicates. Note: some of the name fields have commas and/or parentheses in them. Could this confuse `_.sort` and `_.uniq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code below will print elements which have duplicated name

```
 a = [{ name: 'Damian', age: 1}, {name: 'Ania', age: 1}, {name: 'Damian', age: 2}, {name: 'Joanna', age: 4}] 

 grouped = _.groupBy(a, 'name')

 _.each(grouped, function(elements, name) { if(elements.length > 1) { console.log(elements) }; })
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks for this. Super helpful.